# How to filter out results that are non-checkable in a QTreeWidgetItemIterator?

Tags: python, iterator, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidgetitem

Is it possible to filter a `QTreeWidgetItemIterator` so that items that are not checkable are omitted from the results?

```
TreeList = ({
    'Header1': (('Item11', 'Item12', )),
    'Header2': (('Item21', 'Item22', )),
})

# LOCATED IN `initLayout` METHOD
for key, value in TreeList.items():
    parent = QTreeWidgetItem(self.ListTreeView, [key])
    for val in value:
        child = QTreeWidgetItem([val])
        child.setFlags(child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        parent.addChild(child)

# LOCATED IN `initialize` METHOD
iterator = QTreeWidgetItemIterator(self.ListTreeView)
while iterator.value():
    val = iterator.value()

    try:  # Results in object has not attribute
        if val.isCheckable():
            print('checkable')
    except AttributeError as e:
        print(e)

    iterator += 1
```

In this example, neither `Header1` or `Header2` are checkable, but the items located under them are. When I iterate through the `QTreeWidget`, it returns the entire list.

Looking at the documentation for the [IteratorFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitemiterator.html#IteratorFlag-enum), I can see there are flags that can be set, but I don't understand how to set them in Python, and I'm not sure that any of them would fit my needs.

Right now, `val.isCheckable()` results in an `AttributeError`; which is expected, as `isCheckable()` does not appear to be an attribute of `QTreeWidgetItem` - or is it?

Preferably I would like to filter out non-checkable items, but if this is not possible,  how can I check if the value `isCheckable()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QTreeWidgetItem` class is checkable by default, and there are no accessor methods for the checkable state. So you need to use the item-flags instead:

```
iterator = QTreeWidgetItemIterator(self.ListTreeView)
while iterator.value():
    val = iterator.value()
    if val.flags() & Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable:
        print('checkable')
    iterator += 1
```

Given this, you will also need to explicitly *unset* the flag for items that you *don't* want to be checkable:

```
for key, value in TreeList.items():
    parent = QTreeWidgetItem(self.ListTreeView, [key])
    # remove checkable flag for header items
    parent.setFlags(parent.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
```